# Why are my dataset features IDs undefined in Mapbox GL while I have set them?

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I struggle to set feature IDs using mapbox GL.

I've [read](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/#geojson-generateId) that you can auto-generate IDs using `generateId:true` in your source:

> Whether to generate ids for the geojson features. When enabled, the
> feature.id property will be auto assigned based on its index in the
> features array, over-writing any previous values.

Except that I want to use my data at other places than just the mapbox map (a list of markers aside); so I would like to set them manually because I want to be able to target my feature on the map from my list aside.  So, I don't want to use `generateId:true` here.

[In the doc](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/getting-started/creating-data/), their dataset example is like

```
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "id": "marker-iv1qi3x10",//an ID here
          "title": "Burnham Park",
          "description": "A lakefront park on Chicago's south side.",
          "marker-size": "medium",
          "marker-color": "#1087bf",
          "marker-symbol": "marker-blue"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [
            -87.603735,
            41.829985
          ],
          "type": "Point"
        },
        "id": "0de616c939ce2f31676ff0294c78321b"//another ID here
      }
    ]
  }
```

So they have an ID in the feature object `"id": "0de616c939ce2f31676ff0294c78321b"`, and another ID in the properties of that feature `"id": "marker-iv1qi3x10"`.

I guess that the ID that mapbox uses internally for features (and auto-generated when `generateId` is set to `true` in your source) is the first one.

Let's say I set the IDs manually:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "customPropId01"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          -87.603735,
          41.829985
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "id": "customID01"
    }
  ]
}
```

When inspecting the data when the source has loaded, my custom IDs are still in place (using this code).

```
//when a specific source has been loaded
map.on('sourcedata', (e) => {
  if (e.sourceId !== 'markers') return;
  if (!e.isSourceLoaded) return;
  console.log("SOURCE DATA LOADED",e.source);
});
```

But when I click on a marker on the map and that I log it, **the ID property of my feature has been removed and is now `undefined`**:

[image]

Rather than using my input source data to list my markers, I also had a look at [querySourceFeatures](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#querysourcefeatures), but this doesn't help since it returns only the features in the map bouding box - and I want my listing to display all the features, that is why I need to use the "raw" source data there.

This is driving me crazy.
Does anyone knows why the IDs are unset and how I could fix this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

I found out that you can set `promoteId` to the feature property you want to use as IDs :

```
  map.addSource('markers',{
    type:"geojson",
    data:"http://www.example.com/markers.geojson",
    promoteId:'unique_id'
  })
```

With `promoteId:'unique_id'`, the property `unique_id` of my features will be used to set each feature's ID.

Comment: This doesn't answer how to keep feature.id, only how to use feature.properties.x

Answer (score 4):

Your id is a string. But if you want preserve your id, this string should be cast in integer [like the doc explain](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/616930829be77666615f5657b19614168d939f22/src/style-spec/reference/v8.json#L2869):

> Features are identified by their `id` attribute, which must be an integer or a string that can be cast to an integer.